# True or False Question About Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I 'm new in Stack and I need help with a few questions about linear algebra. I'm trying it but I cannot.

***TRUE OR FALSE***

1) Let $A,B$ and $C$ be $nxn$ matrices such that $C$ is invertible and $B=C.A.{ C }^{ -1 }$, then ${ A }^{ n }={ C }^{ -1 }.{ B }^{ n }.C$

2) If $A\in M_{ nxn }$ Nonsingular matrix, then $det\left( adj\left( A \right)  \right) ={ \left( det\left( A \right)  \right)  }^{ n-1 }$

3) Let $A,B$ and $C$ be $nxn$ matrices, then ${ \left( A.{ B }^{ -1 }+A.C \right)  }^{ t }={ A }^{ t }\left( { \left( { B }^{ t } \right)  }^{ -1 }+{ C }^{ t } \right) $

Help Please!

Comment: No, my first time here

Comment: @Ronny: He is asking for your views on the problem

Comment: I Tried number 1 using determinants but not get anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not giving your views on the problem, I'll give you some hints.

**1)** Can you find an expression for $B^n$ from the given data?

**2)** Well, you know $A^{-1}=\frac{(adj A)}{|A|}$

**3)** Try taking $B=I_n$ i.e. identity $n$x$n$ matrix and find a counterexample.

**Note:** $|A|=det(A)$